# Let $VABC$ be a triangular pyramid with $VA<VB<VC$. Prove that there is a point $P$ inside the triangle $ABC$ such that $VP= \frac{VA+VB+VC}{3}$.

Tags: geometry, inequality

**The drawing**

Let $VABC$ be a triangular pyramid with $VA<VB<VC$. Prove that there is a point $P$ inside the triangle $ABC$ such that $VP= \frac{VA+VB+VC}{3}$.

**The idea**

[image]

Let $VO \perp (ABC)$

The first thought I got is clearly that $AO<BO<CO$ because $VA<VB<VC$ and using the Phytaghora Theorem we get this inequality

I tried imaging P being in different posts such as the midpoint of $AB,BC,AC$ or as the center of the circumscribed circle or inscribed circle of the triangle, in some of them I got that P doesn't satisfy the equality or got to nothing useful to demonstrate.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the formula is correct? Maybe $\frac{VA+VB+VC}3$?.

Comment: @Andrei I checked again in my math book and I wrote it correctly...

Comment: Imagine a tiny triangle $ABC$, and $V$  about the same distance  $d$ from $A$, $B$, $C$. Then every point $P$ inside is also about distance $d$ from $V$.  Andrei is right; there may be a typo in the book

Comment: Indeed, Andrei is right : here is another counter-example : take $A(0,0,0),B(1,0,0),C(0,2,0)$ and $D(0,0,3\varepsilon)$. It will be very very difficult to find $P$ inside the triangle verifying $VP=\varepsilon+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}$... because the maximum value that $VP$ can take is $AC=\sqrt{5}$...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the result to be established is erroneous (printer's typo ?)

Comment: @Andrei I think is as you said $\frac{VA+VB+VC}{3}$. Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: This one should now be a consequence of continuity of distance. That is, the triangle $ABC$ is a connected set, and the function $f(P) = \text{ length of }VP$ from the triangle $ABC$ to the positive real numbers is a continuous function. Therefore, the image of the triangle $ABC$ under $f$ is connected, and we know that the lengths of $VA$ and $VC$ belong in this set, by taking $P=A$ and $P=C$. But a connected subset of $\mathbb R$ must be an interval, hence every real number between $VA$ and $VC$ must also lie in the image, and $\frac{VA+VB+VC}{3}$ is such a number, finishing the proof.

Comment: Of course, this proof uses continuity of distance, so I'm putting it in the comments assuming it's not acceptable here.

Comment: I think you were on the right track with the orthogonal projection. it has to be on the inside of the triangle because pythagoras and strict inequality.  now draw a circle so that it contains all the points with distance VP, it cannot lie completely outside the triangle because VP < VC

Comment: Consider the sphere with center $V$ and radius $VP$. One of $A,B,C$ is inside, one is outside. So...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be a point on the line segment $AB$ such that $VD=\frac{VA+VB}{2}$.

(Such a point $D$ exists. The reason is as follows : Let $A'$ be a point on the half line $VA$ such that $VA'=\frac{VA+VB}{2}$. Let $B'$ be a point on the half line $VB$ such that $VB'=\frac{VA+VB}{2}$. Then, we have $VA'\gt VA$ since $$2VA\lt VA+VB\implies VA\lt \frac{VA+VB}{2}=VA'$$ Similarly, $VB'\lt VB$ since $$2VB\gt VA+VB\implies VB\gt\frac{VA+VB}{2}=VB'$$ Now on the plane $VAB$, let us consider a circle whose center is $V$ with radius $\frac{VA+VB}{2}$. We see that $A',B'$ are on the circle. Since $VA'\gt VA$ and $VB'\lt VB$, there is a point $D$ on the line segment $AB$ such that $D$ is on the circle. For such a point $D$, we have $VD=\frac{VA+VB}{2}$.)

Let $E$ be a point on the line segment $VD$ such that $VE=\frac 23VD$.

Let $F$ be a point on the line segment $VC$ such that $VF=\frac 13VC$.

Let $G$ be a point on the half line $VD$ such that $VG=VE+VF$.

Let $H$ be a point on the half line $VC$ such that $VH=VE+VF$.

Now, since $VD=\frac{VA+VB}{2}$, we have
$$\frac{VA+VB+VC}{3}=\frac{2VD+VC}{3}=VE+VF$$

We have $VG\gt VD$ since
$$\begin{align}&VC-VA+VC-VB\gt 0
\\&\implies VC\gt \frac{VA+VB}{2}
\\&\implies VC\gt VD
\\&\implies \frac 13VC\gt \frac 13VD
\\&\implies VF\gt ED
\\&\implies VF+VE\gt ED+VE
\\&\implies VG\gt VD\end{align}$$

Also, we have $VC\gt VH$ since
$$\begin{align}\frac 23VC\gt\frac 23VD&\implies FC\gt VE
\\&\implies FC+VF\gt VE+VF
\\&\implies VC\gt VH\end{align}$$

Now, on the plane $VCD$, let us consider a circle whose center is $V$ with radius $VE+VF$.

$G,H$ are on the circle with $VG\gt VD$ and $VH\lt VC$.

So, there is a point $P$ on the line segment $CD$ such that $P$ is on the circle.

For such a point $P$, we have $$VP=VE+VF=\frac{VA+VB+VC}{3}. \blacksquare$$